# MySql convert start_date (VARCHAR) column datatype to start_date (DATETIME) without losing data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatables

I have a `start_date(VARCHAR)` column which have the data stored in "`11/06/15 06:00:00 AM`" format.

I'm having issue with Jquery DataTable, it is not sorting this column properly.

I want to convert `start_date(VARCHAR)` column to `start_date(DATETIME)` format.

I tried with couple alter commands it replaces date to `0000-00-00` and not converting it properly.

```sql
UPDATE videos SET `temp_date` = STR_TO_DATE(`start_date`, '%e/%c/%Y %h:%i:%s.%f %p')
```

Please suggest me sql query to fix the issue without losing data.

Comment: Try `STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%e/%c/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')`. Your format has `.%f` part (microseconds) but your date hasn't miscroseconds - `11/06/15 06:00:00 AM`

Comment: In some cases it is giving me NULL. e.g "11/23/15 12:00:00 PM". And second issue it is giving me as a result "2015-06-11 06:00:00". I have now no clue as per the records it was PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of `'11/06/15 06:00:00 AM'` is `'%m/%d/%y %h:%i:%s %p'`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/06/15 06:00:00 AM', '%m/%d/%y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

[Result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=86983080b1392e4f3447c30f430aa237):

```
2015-06-11 06:00:00
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) you can find all the specifiers that you can use with [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: Two issues I'm facing now. first no clue about the AM/PM. Second for most of data it is giving NULL .e.g "11/23/15 12:00:00 PM"

Comment: You should have posted "11/23/15 12:00:00 PM" as sample data because from this it is obvious that 11 is the month and 23 is the day. See my edited answer.